# knockout sorting doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js

My setup is as follows...

I have a service which brings back data from a stored procedure to a UI in no particular order. The UI binds the data to an MVC partial using knockout which looks like this...

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "People List"; }

<h2>People List</h2>

<table id="people">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Job Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 125px;"><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></td>
            <td style="width: 75px;"><span data-bind="text: Gender"></span></td>
            <td style="width: 105px;"><span data-bind="text: JobTitle"></span></td>
            <td style="width: 300px;"><span data-bind="text: JobDescription"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button style="margin-top: 15px;" data-bind="click: sortByName">Sort by Name</button>
```

The JS for the VM looks like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Person(data) {
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.Gender = ko.observable(data.Gender);
        this.JobTitle = ko.observable(data.JobTitle);
        this.JobDescription = ko.observable(data.JobDescription);
    }

    function PersonListVM() {
        var self = this;

        self.people = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("DisplayPeople", "People")',
            function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    self.people.push(new Person(results[i]));
                }
            });

        self.sortByName = function () {
            self.people.sort(function (x, y) {
                return x["Name"] == y["Name"] ? 0 : (x["Name"] < y["Name"] ? -1 : 1);
            });
        };
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new PersonListVM());
</script>
```

I can get and display data with no problem, even adding another dummy person in a VM function goes off without a hitch. But sorting by name seems to do nothing. There are no errors, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. This is supposed to be a pretty simple search, what am I missing?

**PS**: The reason I'm supplying the property name as a string is because I want to make a sortable, paginated grid out of this table, sorting by table headers. My goal is to be able to pass in any valid property on which the table can be sorted dynamically but this is just as experiment working up to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you're accessing your properties using array syntax, they're still ko.observables.  You need to "unwrap" the observable to get at the value.

Try this instead:

```
return x['Name']() == y['Name']() ? 0 : (x['Name']() < y['Name']() ? -1 : 1);
```

Comment: ah yes I think you are correct, I did not see his Person properties were observables... nice catch! got my upvote

Comment: I knew it was bound to be something silly like forgetting to put some parens. No wonder these properties were coming back as a JS function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head have you tried using dot syntax to access the person object properties instead of array syntax?

```
self.people.sort(function (x, y) {
            return x.Name == y.Name ? 0 : (x.Name < y.Name ? -1 : 1);
        });
```